# How can php return a value to jquery that is an html file?

Tags: jquery

I want to perform an jquery request to php and then I want php to return a value that is an html which is going to be attached on the original page.
The code for jquery is something like this:

```
$.get("phpfile.php",{'variable':variable},function(response){

$("paragraph_to_display_response").html(response);
```

I want php to return as response an html file which is actually an upload file form. Can I do that?Php code should look something like this:

```
$variable=$_GET['variable'];
//perform some checks with variable
echo ???//How can I echo an html file?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should have a container for the Response f.E:

```
<div class="result">This will be replaced by AJAX</div>
<div class="click">Go</div>
```

Your javascript should look like this:

```
var variable = 'VAR';
$(".click").click(function() {
  $.get('phpfile.php', {'variable':variable}, function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
  });
});
```

You also have to trigger the request above by adding a click event to some element in your HTML.

Your PHP should simply just return the HTML you need.

phpfile.php

```
<?php
$variable=$_GET['variable'];
echo $variable.': <input name="file" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100000" accept="text/*">';
```

Comment: Yeah but this way I have to write to the php file all the html code from the beginning. What if I have allready written the code <input name="file" type...etc...>  in an html file called upload_form, how could then php echo that upload_form file?

Comment: you could open the file with php and echo it: $form = file_get_contents($yourpathtothefile); echo $form;

Comment: or if its a complete file with <html> etc you might consider using an iframe.